# Google SignIn Flutter Error: Assertion Failed

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-signin

I am creating a fLutter app and I am trying to login using Firebase google_sign_in. But I am getting some error: **Assertion Failed**

That's my function:

```
void signInWithGoogle() async {
    final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
    try {
      GoogleSignInAccount? account = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
      if (account != null) {
        final GoogleSignInAuthentication _authAccount =
            await account.authentication;
        final AuthCredential _credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
          idToken: _authAccount.idToken,
          accessToken: _authAccount.accessToken,
        );

        UserCredential userCredential =
            await _auth.signInWithCredential(_credential);
        userCredential.user;
        await saveUser(account);
      }
    } on Exception catch (error) {
      AppLogger.e(error);
    }
  }

saveUser(GoogleSignInAccount account) {
    userRf.doc(account.email).set({
      "email": account.email,
      "name": account.displayName,
      "profilepic": account.photoUrl,
    });
  }
```

```
Error: Assertion failed:
..\…\lib\google_sign_in_web.dart:89
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 266:49      throw_
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 29:3        assertFailed
packages/google_sign_in_web/google_sign_in_web.dart 89:20                                                                      initWithParams
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54                runBody
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 123:5                _async
packages/google_sign_in_web/google_sign_in_web.dart 86:30                                                                      initWithParams
packages/google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart 290:39                                                                             [_ensureInitialized]
packages/google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart 271:11                                                                             _callMethod
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54                runBody                                                                         _addMethodCall                  <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 594:14                    <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 288:16                    loggedHandler
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 179:80                    <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 334:14  _checkAndCall
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 339:39  dcall
```

I am new to Flutter. Please help me out.

Comment: Which line of code did you get this error? 
Did you set up firebase well? 
Did you get the firebase token?

Comment: don't know. Direct this error comes out

Comment: I have exactly the same problem tried many things and nothing helped.